# When to mark `JNIEnv *env` const?

Tags: java-native-interface, constants

The question is really simple, as I am still learning about it:

When should one mark `JNIEnv *env` as `const JNIEnv *env`?

Are there any implications that a newbie wouldn't think of?

I've googled but couldn't find much related information/discussion.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to use `env`, pretty much never. A `const JNIEnv *` is a pointer to `const JNIEnv`, and in C++ at least you cannot call a non-const method through a pointer to a const object (and AFAIK none of the methods in `JNIEnv` are marked as `const`). If what you really meant was that you wanted to make the pointer itself `const` (i.e. `JNIEnv * const env`), then I suppose go ahead if that's something you want to do.

Comment: @Michael. Thanks for your reply! So that's why I've seen so little discussions about the pointer to `const JNIEnv *env`. So to do non trivial work, most likely the native codes will be calling through `JNIEnv *env` to do some modification to the "environment". Is this correct, since this is the only way that I can imagine why it is not marked as pointer to const.